# Merge two arrays of dictionaries in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, d3.js

I have two arrays of dictionaries which look something like this:

```
var lat = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:50.7825333},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:50.7826},...];
var lon = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:-1.3075833},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:-1.3076},...];
```

You might have guessed that one is an array of latitudes and one of longitudes!

I would like an elegant way of merging time, lat, lon into one array. Both arrays contain the same keys (I should check that this is always the case!).

```
var latLon = [{time:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", lat:50.7825333, lon:-1.3075833},...]
```

I have thrown something together that works but isn't pretty (ie iterate both arrays and append to a new one) but it feels like there must be a more stylish way using Object.assign with some nice lamdas. I am also using the D3.js library if that contains any useful methods.

Comment: It's best that you add the code you've tried to your question.

Comment: I'm at work and don't have a lot of time to ensure this is right, but you might look into lodash and/or underscore's `zip` method -- https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method to generate the new array( assuming both arrays are in the same order ).

```js
var lat = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:50.7825333},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:50.7826}];
var lon = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:-1.3075833},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:-1.3076}];


var res = lat
  // iterate over the first array
  .map(function(o, i) {
    // generate the array element
    // where get values from element and
    // get value from second array using
    // the index
    return {
      time: o.key,
      lat: o.value,
      lon: lon[i].value
    }
  })

console.log(res);

// with ES6 arrow function
var res1 = lat.map((o, i) => ({time: o.key, lat: o.value, lon: lon[i].value}))


console.log(res1);
```

---

**FYI :** In case related array elements are not in same order then you need to get the element from the second array by comparing time value(you can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method) or you can generate a hashmap to map the object.

**With [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method :**

```js
var lat = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:50.7825333},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:50.7826}];
var lon = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:-1.3075833},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:-1.3076}];



var res = lat
  .map(function(o) {
    return {
      time: o.key,
      lat: o.value,
      // get object by using find method
      lon: lon.find(function(o1) {
        return o1.key === o.key;
      }).value
    }
  })

console.log(res);

// with ES6 arrow function
var res1 = lat.map(o => ({
  time: o.key,
  lat: o.value,
  lon: lon.find(o1 => o1.key === o.key).value
}))

console.log(res1);
```

**More efficient approach using a hashmap for referencing:**

```js
var lat = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:50.7825333},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:50.7826}];
var lon = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:-1.3075833},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:-1.3076}];

// generate reference hashmap for getting 
// value using the datetime string
var ref = lon.reduce(function(obj, o) {
  // set reference
  obj[o.key] = o.value;
  // return the reference object
  return obj;
  // set initial value as an empty object
}, {});

var res = lat
  .map(function(o) {
    return {
      time: o.key,
      lat: o.value,
      // get value from generated reference object
      lon: ref[o.key]
    }
  })

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid using `find()` if there's any chance you will be dealing will a lot of items. `find()` needs to search through the second array for *every item* in lat which is not efficient.

You can do this with a single `map` and `reduce` if you build a dictionary on the first loop and make the new array on the second.

This also allows the `lat` and `lon` arrays to be in different orders.

```js
var lat = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:50.7825333},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:50.7826}];
var lon = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:-1.3075833},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:-1.3076}];

var obj = lat.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.key] = {time: c.key, lat:c.value}, a), {});
var arr = lon.map(lon => Object.assign(obj[lon.key], {lon: lon.value}));

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: *I would avoid using find() if there's any chance you will be dealing will a lot of items*. Actually with `find` you will loop until you find the requested object, while with your actual code, you will **loop over the whole array** twice, one with `reduce()` and the next with `.map()`, so I think using `find()` will be more performant. ;)

Comment: @chsdk the `find()` in your answer is inside the `map()`, which means `find()` gets called for every item in `lat`. If there are 100 items then `find()` is called 100 times. That's much worse than 2 loops.

Comment: Yes I agree with you may be in case there are many items (BTW 100 are not so huge), but `find()` will quite as soon as it finds the `object`, anyway theorically it's worse, but they are implemented to guarantee performance. But all these problems will be really ommitted if the objects where ordred the same way in both arrays.
But anyway Not to take anything from the great solution you gave. :)

Comment: You are using ES6 arrow functions, how good is the browser support for those ?

Comment: @Taurus https://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions it looks like a little less than 80% worldwide.

Comment: @Mark_M That is great, I never expected it to be that much.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on the `key` time. Assuming there are no keys/times the same then you can do this:

```
var lat = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:50.7825333},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:50.7826}];
var lon = [{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:32.000Z", value:-1.3075833},{key:"2017-09-20T11:51:33.000Z", value:-1.3076}];

var obj = {}, arr = lat.concat(lon);

arr.forEach(function(x){
    obj[x.key] ? obj[x.key]["lon"] = x.value : obj[x.key] = {lat: x.value, time: x.key};
});

var latlon = Object.keys(obj).map(function(x){
    return obj[x];
});
```

You are concatenating the 2 arrays to make one array. Then you are creating a dictionary using the time as a key (this is where it assumes that you do not have two lats and two longs with the same times). Since you know you are first getting the lats, your next key match should be the lons.